# Navigation Bar not showing up

Tags: swift

This is my code in scene delegate

```
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
          window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
          window?.windowScene = windowScene
          let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:HomeViewViewController())
          window?.rootViewController = navController
          window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

And in my home page I do not see any navigation  Bar

I am using xib and Xcode 13.1

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Sabez so the designated entry point is XIB right? You are unable to see `self.title` text onto the HomeViewViewController ?

Comment: @RTXGamer Yes I get nav title. But the the backgroud color is not the default. is it because i am using the latest xcode?

Comment: yes its transparent by default in iOS 15, https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/684454

Comment: @RTXGamer Ahh Okay thanks! Didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you initialise a rootController programmatically you also have to remove reference to main storyboard from:

## 1.Info.plist

[image]

## 2. Deployment info

[image]